# Losing polarized photons due to re-fraction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light

After sending unpolarized photons through a vertical polarizer about 50% continue on to a second vertical polarizer. Beyond that if you put another vertical polarizer it is claimed that nearly all photons will make it through. I was wondering how many photons are lost due to refraction at the edges of the slits. And wouldn’t it be significant?

Comment: Polarizing materials don't necessarily have slits.  I'm not sure what your setup is.  Can you describe more what these slits are (or what you're using them for)?

Comment: I just mean any slit that is used in a polarizing experiment. Example three vertical slits in a row. The light begins with a certain intensity and after the first slit is reduced 50%. After that, what stops the photons from being lost due to re-fraction on the edges of the remaining slits?

Comment: Wouldn't they be lost if the slits were present without a polarizer in place as well?

Comment: I would think so but when reading about multiple parallel polarizers it is always said that virtually all the photons will make it through.

Comment: Virtually all make it through the polarizer.  That doesn't mean it won't be refracted by the slit.  But that's a separate process.

Comment: Why is this being downloaded? It’s a good question and import it to what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can lose photons for lots of reasons.  Loss due to polarization effects would be added to loss for any other reason.

Imagine setting up the experiment with the slits in place, but with no polarizing material.  You're going to get a certain intensity at the end that you can detect.

When you add a polarizer in there, you shouldn't have to worry (much) about refraction or edge effects from the slits, because you've already measured the intensity with that taken into account.

For real polarizers, you'll also lose some intensity when aligned and some light will pass when anti-aligned because they're not perfect.  But if you're running an experiment, you just need to get the spec sheet from the manufacturer to take that into account.